# flutter firebase: streamBuilder search property returns different data

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, datetimepicker

I have a date search app. However, when I click on a specific date it doesn't return the value I requested for. But when I search a date before the actual date it returns the actual date I queried.
For example I want to search for values which have the date `31.03.2023` and I select that date, it doesn't return any value.

But when I search for values which have the date 31.03.2023 I have to select the date `30.03.2023` and then this will return the values for `31.03.2023`.

This is my code:

```
var date = '';
DateTime _dateTime = DateTime.now();

  void _showDatePicker() {
    showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime.now(),
      lastDate: DateTime(
          DateTime.now().year + 1), // +1 is to limit the date to 1 year ahead
    ).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _dateTime = value!;
      });
    });
  }

child: Scaffold(
child: Column(
children: <Widget>[
GestureDetector(
onTap: () { _showDatePicker();
            setState(() 
         {date = selectedDate;});},
          child: Text(selectedDate,),])
ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => AdsListViewScreen( date: date)));},
                child: const Text(
                  "Search",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),)
```

Any help?

This is the method I used to store  the data

```
DateTime _dateTime = DateTime.now().toLocal();

  void _showDatePicker() {
    showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now().toLocal(),
      firstDate: DateTime.now().toLocal(),
      lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 1)
          .toLocal(), // +1 is to limit the date to 1 year ahead
    ).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _dateTime = value!;
      });
    });
  }

ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){Date:("dd.MM").format(_dateTime.toLocal()),}//*****I defined the `Date` in a model
);
if (_formkey.currentState!.validate()) {authProvider.saveAdsDataToFirebase
(context:context,adsModel:adsModel,onSuccess:() {authProvider.saveAdsDataToFirebase();});} } else {failed();onSuccess =false;},);} 
child: const Text('Submit'));
```

And I used `StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>` to retrieve the data

My AdsModel

```
class AdsModel { String deptDate; 
                    
                  AdsModel({required this.deptDate,})
    
                  //form map
                 factory AdsModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
                 return AdsModel(deptDate: map["Departure date"] ?? '',)}
    
                 //to map
                 Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
                 return {"Departure date": deptDate,}}
    }
```

My authProver

```
class AuthProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
                           AdsModel? _adsModel;
                           AdsModel get adsModel => _adsModel!;
    
    void saveAdsDataToFirebase({
        BuildContext? context,
        AdsModel? adsModel,
        Function? onSuccess,
      }) async {
        _isLoading = true;
        notifyListeners();
        try {
          // uploadingto database
          await _firebaseFirestore
              .collection("ADS")
              .doc(_uid)
              .set(adsModel!.toMap())
              .then((value) {
            onSuccess!();
            _isLoading = false;
            notifyListeners();
          });
        } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
          showSnackBar(context!, e.message.toString());
          _isLoading = false;
          notifyListeners();
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: This may be a time zone issue.

Comment: So how do I solve it?

Comment: There are different ways to deal with it . It depends on how you store data in your database, what query you use to retrieve that data, and what value you pass to that query.

Comment: Andrei Volgin - The question u asked has been aswered in the edited post. please check and see what's wrong

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to compare two Datetime variables in the same time zone. DateTime class has methods for you to convert: `_dateTime = _dateTime.toUtc(); _dateTime = _dateTime.toLocal()` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html

Comment: I added the .toLocal() in both cases but the situation remains the same

Comment: I think the Date data is in UTC in your database as it should be. Please try to convert your _dateTime  to UTC before building the query.

Comment: I changed the toLocal() to toUtc but still the problem persists

Comment: You should save date in UTC to database then query it in UTC as well. Your problem may be related to its time (hh:mm:ss) when you compare them in the same time zone, please check.

Comment: I don't really get. I thought that's what I did in my previous comment. Could you please show me what u mean in codes

Comment: What Is the Date field type in the your database? DateTime/String?
Show me the code where your model is saved and before query data.

Comment: this is what I had:-----

 var date = '';   -------DateTime _dateTime = DateTime.now();

Comment: My AdsModel and My authProvider are in the edited post